# View JSON file in Midnight Commander using jq

Tags: jq, mc

So there is that awesome tool for working with JSON data called [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

And there is that awesome linux file manager called [mc](https://midnight-commander.org/).

One day (today) I came around an idea to integrate these two, so I could easily preview JSON files in a pretty/formatted way using F3 keyboard shortcut when in Midnight Commander.

I opened MC extension file using `Command` → `Edit extension file` menu actions and then added following to such opened configuration file:

```
# json
regex/\.json$
   View=%view{ascii} jq < %f
```

I thought it is straightforward, but unexpectedly it does not work: trying to view the JSON (F3) results in error popup with contents of `jq`'s help page (the same as when you type `jq` by itself), so starting with: "*jq - commandline JSON processr [version 1.5]...*"

Can anybody tell me why this configuration is incorrect?

Answer (score 7):

Two minutes after I submitted my question I've been revealed.

I thought that maybe `jq` does not produce standard output... It led me to this question: [How to use `jq` in a shell pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247228/how-to-use-jq-in-a-shell-pipeline) and so I have modified the extension file to look like:

```
# json
regex/\.json$
    View=%view{ascii} jq '.' < %f
```

And now it works as expected, piping result of `jq` to the internal `mc` viewer.

Thank you, me ;)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use redirection **<** here, you could use just a plain filename **%f**:

```json
# json
regex/\.json$
    View=%view{ascii} jq '.' %f
```

and as you [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49531735/1832863) you have to use a simple filter: **.**

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering, why this no longer works. In version 4.8.29, MC switched from `mc.ext` to the new `mc.ext.ini` ini file, which has slightly different syntax. The new entry should look like this

```
[JSON]
Regex=\.json$
View=%view{ascii} jq '.' < %f
```

The `[JSON]` line is necessary.