# Why is my jq failing on my JSON?

Tags: json, bash, curl, jq, wp-api

Haven't used `jq` before but I'm wanting to build a shell script that will get a JSON response and extract just the values.  To learn I thought I would try on my blog's WP API but for some reason I'm getting an error of:

> jq: error (at :322): Cannot index array with string "slug"

When researching for and testing previous questions:

- [jq: Cannot index array with string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543829/jq-cannot-index-array-with-string)
- [jq is sed for JSON](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/jq-is-sed-for-json)
- [JSON array to bash variables using jq](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/413878/json-array-to-bash-variables-using-jq)
- [How to use `jq` in a shell pipeline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33247228/how-to-use-jq-in-a-shell-pipeline)
- [How to extract data from a JSON file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243428/how-to-extract-data-from-a-json-file)

The above reading I've tried to code:

```
URL="http://foobar.com"
RESPONSE=$(curl -so /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" $URL)
WPAPI="/wp-json/wp/v2"
IDENTIFIER="categories"

if (("$RESPONSE" == 200)); then
    curl -s {$URL$WPAPI"/"$IDENTIFIER"/"} | jq '.' >> $IDENTIFIER.json
    result=$(jq .slug $IDENTIFIER.json)
    echo $result
else
    echo "Not returned status 200";
fi
```

An additional attempt changing the `jq` after the `curl`:

```
curl -s {$URL$WPAPI"/"$IDENTIFIER"/"} | jq '.' | $IDENTIFIER.json
result=(jq -r '.slug' $IDENTIFIER.json)
echo $result
```

I can modify the uncompress with the python JSON tool:

```
result=(curl -s {$URL$WPAPI"/"$IDENTIFIER"/"} | python -m json.tool > $IDENTIFIER.json)
```

I can save the JSON to a file but when I use `jq` I cannot get just the slug and here are my other trys:

```
catCalled=$(curl -s {$URL$WPAPI"/"$IDENTIFIER"/"} | python -m json.tool | ./jq -r '.slug')
echo $catCalled
```

My end goal is to try to use `jq` in a shell script and build a slug array  with `jq`.  What am I doing wrong in my `jq` and can I use `jq` on a string without creating a file?

---

Return from `curl` after uncompress per comment request:

```
[
  {
    "id": 4,
    "count": 18,
    "description": "",
    "link": "http://foobar.com/category/foo/",
    "name": "Foo",
    "slug": "foo",
    "taxonomy": "category",
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "count": 9,
    "description": "",
    "link": "http://foobar.com/category/bar/",
    "name": "Bar",
    "slug": "bar",
    "taxonomy": "category",
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "count": 1,
    "description": "",
    "link": "http://foobar.com/category/mon/",
    "name": "Mon",
    "slug": "mon",
    "taxonomy": "category",
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "count": 8,
    "description": "",
    "link": "http://foobar.com/category/fort/",
    "name": "Fort",
    "slug": "fort",
    "taxonomy": "category",
  }
]
```

eventually my goal is trying to get the name of the slug's into an array like:

```
catArray=('foo','bar','mon', 'fort')
```

Comment: Can you post the server response?

Comment: @hnicke added JSON example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues here:

1. `slug` is not a root level element in your example json. The root level element is an array. If you want to access the `slug` property of each element of the array, you can do so like this:

   ```
   jq '.[].slug' $IDENTIFIER.json
   ```
2. Your example json has trailing commas after the last property of each array element. Remove the commas after `"taxonomy": "category"`.

If I take your sample json, remove the errant commas, save it to a plain text file called `test.json` and run the following command:

```
jq '.[].slug' test.json
```

I get the following output:

```
"foo"
"bar"
"mon"
"fort"
```

Comment: thanks the `'.[].slug'` is what I needed and +1 for that.

Answer (score 0):

### Preprocessing

Unfortunately, the JSON-like data shown as having been produced by curl is not strictly JSON.  jq does not have a "relaxed JSON" mode, so in order to use jq, you will have to preprocess the JSON-like data, e.g. using hjson (see http://hjson.org/):

```
$ hjson -j input.qjson > input.json
```

### jq

With the JSON in input.json:

```
$ jq -c 'map(.slug)' input.json
["foo","bar","mon","fort"]
```

Answer (score 0):

your string is not json, notice how the last member of your objects ends with a comma,

`{foo:"bar",baz:9,}`

this is legal in javascript, but it's illegal in json. if you are supposed to be receiving json from that endpoint, then contact the people behind it and tell them to fix the bug (it's breaking the json specs by ending objects's last member with a comma, which is illegal in json.) - until it's fixed, i guess you can patch it with a little regex, but it's a dirty quickfix, and probably not very reliable, but running it through

`perl -p -0777 -e 's/\"\,\s*}/\"}/g;'` makes it legal json..